# HTML buttons work fine on desktop do not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a website and while the desktop version is finished i am still fighting with the mobile one. So anyways, every single button that uses js to do its thing doesnt work, while normal buttons with links work just fine. The issue also does not appear on chrome using the 'toggle device toolbar' option, which should technically simulate touch events.

This is how a sample button looks like:

```
 <a class="button" id="upload-media-button">Upload</a>
```

And this is the js that uses it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#upload-media-button').on('click touchstart', function(){
        dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
        dropperForm.className = '';
        isUploadFormVisible = 1;
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");

    });
}
```

Comment: pass `event` as argument in event handler. And add `event.preventDefault()` as first line in your function

Comment: Downvoting without giving any useful info as of why? I am seriously asking, and I've tried different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly why this is happening.

But this may be case. We should disable the default behavior of browser.

As it is an `anchor` tag, browser have its own handling.

Like modify your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#upload-media-button').on('click touchstart', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
    dropperForm.className = '';
    isUploadFormVisible = 1;
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");

  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, the buttons still do not click at all.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `touchstart` with `tap` like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#upload-media-button').on('click tap', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
     dropperForm.className = '';
     isUploadFormVisible = 1;
     $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  });
});
```

this is assuming that you have included jQuery Mobile in your project. (which I highly recommend you do).

Comment: I would like to include jQuery mobile, especially if it fixes the issue this easily, however the only issue is that it's incompatible with the version of jQuery i am using (jquery 3.4.1, j-mobile 1.4.5)